# TypeError: a.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am following a backbone.js for beginners tutorial, and I've got stuck at the first hurdle. I get the error `TypeError: a.apply is not a function` in  firebug (Firefox 20.0.1).
I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Backbone Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var Router = new Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home'
            }    
        });

        var router = new Router();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using these older versions of *jquery*, *underscore* and *backbone* because they are the versions used in the tutorial. I tried using current versions of all, and I get a similar error: "TypeError: *i*.apply is not a function".

The error happens when an instance of Router is created, ie the line: `var router = new Router();` above.

Is the error to do with my set-up? WAMP, or the code, or the libraries? I can't understand it as it's the same to the letter as the [tutorial](https://gumroad.com/l/backbone-beginner-screencast).

Comment: You are calling "new" twice.

Comment: thx StuR. schoolboy error. no wonder there wasn't already an answer on here! :$

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change

```
    var Router = new Backbone.Router.extend({
```

To

```
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
```

When you're extending those classes, you only need to invoke `extend`, which will return the constructor function that you'll call `new` on later.

Comment: You guys are the absolute nuts. Such a schoolboy error. Couldn't see it for looking. Unfortunately, I can't upvote you because I need at least 15 rep points. :$

Comment: Yeah, this one has bitten me once before, too. :)